# How to extend electrical pulse

Tags: power-electronics

I am building a project and I've come across a problem I can't solve. I need to have an output of about 5 seconds when a button is pressed. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: "about 5seconds"  how precise?

Comment: @JonRB no precision, it's just for a lighting effect

Answer (score 1):

You need a monostable "one-shot" multivibrator. This is very easily done with a 555 timer:

[image]

The output pulse duration can be calculated by T = 1.1*R1*C1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LTC-6993 or LTC-6994 TimerBlox.
http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6994-1
shows the device capabilities, and a tool to get a schematic ready to work,
with a delay of 5sec.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll try the one with the 555 which I already have